# Select fewer fields in populated data using query for Strapi

Tags: strapi

The idea is to get localizations of a product, which ID we know, by populating `localizations` field. So result of the query ( `{{strapiUrl}}/products/2?populate=localizations` ) could look like an [example](https://%60%7B%7BstrapiUrl%7D%7D/products/2?populate=localizations%60):

```json
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "title en",
            // ...
            "localizations": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "attributes": {
                            "title": "title ka",
                            "locale": "ka",
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

I'd like to use [filter](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#field-selection) by and get only the fields in order to get only the `id` field of the `localizations` filed, possibly, that matches `"locale": "ka"` only. Otherwise, we have to just get [0] the first index of it.

So the expected output after "filtering" the returned object would not include some other fields of the item with `id=1`, but just `locale` of it:

```json
// expected output
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "title en",
            // ...
            "localizations": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "attributes": {
                            // want only locale
                            "locale": "ka",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Just to be clear - we need to not get anything than `locale` in `data.attributes.localizations[0].data.attributes.locale` without the need to filter it on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out combining few sections of documentation:

- [Combining Population with other operators](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#combining-population-with-other-operators)
- [Getting localized entries with the `locale` parameter](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/i18n#getting-localized-entries-with-the-locale-parameter)

So, if you need to get limited amount of the other localized object (like only `id` and `locale` of requested `id` of the product (in my case `2`), the solution is this:

`GET: {{strapiUrl}}/products/2?populate[localizations][fields]=locale`